# Title Command invisible in Flat orange theme in CodeName One

Tags: codenameone

I'm developing an app, i chose the flat orange theme but the tittlecommand isn't visible, just appears if I slide to the right and it appears

[image]

I checked the theme.res in the titlecommand unselected item but it seems ok

[image]

if I click on it nothing happens, only when I slide it to the right

[image]

How could I make the tittle command appears when it is unselected?

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

UPDATE 01/15/2020

The container appears with width=0 and height=0.

But how could I change it.

[image]

The code of the slide menu is

```
    Style s = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("TitleCommand");
    FontImage icon = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_TITLE, s);
    Image logo = res.getImage("index.jpg");
    Container topBar = BorderLayout.west(new Label(logo));
    topBar.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,new Label("Los del Camino","SidemenuTagline"));
    getToolbar().addCommandToLeftBar("",icon,null);
    getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(topBar);        
    getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Inicio",FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, e -> new Hola().show());
    getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Estudios",FontImage.MATERIAL_BOOK,  e -> {} );
    getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Calendario", FontImage.MATERIAL_CALENDAR_TODAY, e -> new Calendario(res).show());
    getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("Documentos", FontImage.MATERIAL_FILE_PRESENT, e -> {});
    getToolbar().addComponentToSideMenu(new Label(" ", "SideCommand"));
    getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToSideMenu("ACERCA DE", FontImage.MATERIAL_LIVE_HELP , e -> {});
```

Comment: Check the UI in the Component Inspector tool, do you see the components there?
What's their size? Is it large enough to see?

Comment: Thanks [ShaiAlmog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756809/shai-almog), if you could help me with I updated yesterday.

Comment: That is odd. It might be impacted by the regression in paint that other developers have experienced. Try invoking `setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true)` before calling `Form.show` and see if this works around the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot [Shai Almog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/756809/shai-almog), your suggestion works perfect!!!

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this issue by haven't been successful.  Can you create self-contained test case and file an issue in the issue tracker?  I'd like to make it so that you don't need to use setAllowEnableLayoutOnPaint(true) ever.